# When should one use Posing in cocoa?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I understand that one class can pose as another class, but in what situation should I use it? Please give me an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is never.  [The method that makes it possible is deprecated in 10.5](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-poseAsClass_) and apparently isn't even there in 64 bit builds.

Comment: Yup. Posing is fragile and nasty business.   It was deprecated because it was pretty much always the wrong answer.